# VBA to insert marker or some kind of identification? Idea?

Tags: excel, vba, signature

I am developing a tool to make a revision documents using excel VBA , I import excel files into our tool and manipulate them and export them , and  for the second revision we import the old document and manipulate them and create a new document. So i want to add some kind of identification to the documents created by our tool , so that next time the program will identify as a previous document created with this tool.

Is there is any way to add something to excel file like excel signature and read them next time with vba? I dont want to write anything inside the cells in the workbook.

Any idea?.

Comment: Do you only want to identify documents initially created with your tool? Or do you want to check that the last one who touched the document was your tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the Author of the document?

```
Sub ChangeAuthor()
ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author").Value = "ExcelProductionMacro"
End Sub
```

and to retrieve

```
Public Function GetAuthor() As String    
GetAuthor = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author").Value   
End Function
```

In case you are interested, here is a complete list of document properties you can access.

Others may be useful, such as `Last Author`, `Category`, `Comments`

[BuiltInDocumentProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.builtindocumentproperties.aspx)